# ModelMapper cannot convert from plain DTO to entity with complex field

Tags: modelmapper

Is there a way to convert from plain DTO like:

```
class DTO {
   private Set<String> prop;
}
```

to entity like:

```
class Entity {
   private Nested nested;
}

class Nested {
   private Set<String> prop;
}
```

When I try default configuration nested field remains empty.

What should be configured?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functionality of the [deep mapping](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#deep-mapping)

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.createTypeMap(DTO.class, Entity.class)
            .addMappings(mapping -> mapping.<Set<String>>map(DTO::getProp, (dest, v) -> dest.getNested().setProp(v)));

mapper.createTypeMap(Entity.class, DTO.class)
            .addMappings(mapping -> mapping.map(src -> src.getNested().getProp(), DTO::setProp));
```

Comment: That's true. But suppose that I have a class with 100 fields. I would need to add mappings for each of them and would completely lose the benefit of ModelMapper library since this would be the same as if I would write my own mapper function. So, I need to specify this somehow generic, based on type.

Comment: Could you provide more complex example? 
Based on type? Each of your fields has it's own type? What if you have two `Set<String>` fileds?

Comment: If I have two Set<String> fields I would need to create two mappings according to your code. So, number of mappings would grow as number of fields grow, requiring me change configuration each time I add or remove a field.